# How can I change the owner of a process?

Tags: 14.04, php

Hi I've just completed a tech test on Ubuntu and have come across a problem where I needed to change the user of the PHP process to fix a broken web site. I believe the user was "foo" but needed to be "www-data". I was told at the end that "chowning the process" was the fix, I just want to know how to do it for future reference.

So the same way you would chown the user of a file (I assume) but just for a process. I have searched and searched but I wonder if I am looking for the wrong command? Or would this be changed in a config file somewhere maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to externally change the user or group of a running process in Linux. What you can do is change the configuration of whatever you're running to use the new user from the next time it runs. That depends on how you have installed and configured PHP (or rather, whatever is running PHP for you - apache, php-fpm, etc.).

Comment: Processes can change their *own* user ID, but of course they need appropriate privileges for that which is likely not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it man, if you can kindly share with us.
check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401774/change-owner-of-a-currently-running-process

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/860565)

Comment: @N0rbert: Looks like the gist of the answer is provided in-line: "You can't do it man". The link is just for further details.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a design flaw of the Linux kernel, that credential changes occurs only on disk but not in memory. To put it specifically, when credentials (UID, GID, or supplementary group list) are changed, all existing processes will continue to use their previous credentials and enjoy access to previously granted data. And there is not a single API function to propagate credential change throughout the system (i.e., all processes). As a result of this defect, no user-level programs can do what you want. You need a kernel module to do that. I have just tried to make one and it works on simple programs. (https://github.com/xuancong84/supgroup)

However, in general it is not a good idea to do so because in general a program can have lots of interactions, e.g., opened file handles, child processes/threads running on other CPU cores, bound pipes, opened devices, etc. Thus, changing the UID/GID while running can lead to many undefined behavior among which some can cause error (e.g., broken pipe, aborted I/O communication), some can turn out hazardous (e.g., system crash). I have tested that this program works on simple programs (such as `nc -l 8080`), but on a much bigger complex program running many threads on many CPU cores and GPU CUDA cores, having heavy network activity and disk I/O activity, I am not sure what will happen.